# IKImageBrowserView lazy loading?

Tags: cocoa, lazy-loading, ikimagebrowserview, imagekit

In order to work with the `IKImageBrowserView`, one must implement a datasource with the following methods

```
– numberOfItemsInImageBrowser:
– imageBrowser:itemAtIndex:
```

This is not dissimilar to `NSTableView`, which has the following datasource methods

```
– numberOfRowsInTableView:
– tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:
```

However, the disturbing difference is that whereas `NSTableView` takes into account what's currently visible before calling `– tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`, `IKImageBrowserView` seems to iterate over the entire range given in `– numberOfItemsInImageBrowser:` and ask for `imageBrowser:itemAtIndex:`. Unfortunately, the datasource is sometimes backed by hundreds of thousands of items, loading all the unnecessary ones is a terrible waste. Is there anyway to make `IKImageBrowserView` only load the items visible, (+preloading of course) just like the `NSTableView` does?

**Update**

I tried writing a `NSProxy` subclass and it indeed worked. (well, more on that in a sec) It looks like this

```
// .h file

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ILArrayItemProxy : NSProxy

- (id)initWithArray:(id)array index:(NSUInteger)index;

+ (id)proxyWithArray:(id)array index:(NSUInteger)index;

@end

// .m file

#import "ILArrayItemProxy.h"

@interface ILArrayItemProxy() {
    id _array;
    NSUInteger _index;
}

@property (readonly) id target;

@end

@implementation ILArrayItemProxy

- (id)initWithArray:(id)array index:(NSUInteger)index {
    _array = array;
    _index = index;
    return self;
}

- (id)target {
    return [_array objectAtIndex:_index];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)sel {
    return [self.target methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {
    [invocation invokeWithTarget:self.target];
}
+ (id)proxyWithArray:(id)array index:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [[ILArrayItemProxy alloc] initWithArray:array index:index];
}

@end
```

Now, when the imageBrowser asks for `– imageBrowser:itemAtIndex:`, I would return

```
[ILArrayItemProxy proxyWithArray:self.arrangedObjects index:index];
```

This works very well! Lazy loading is indeed achieved and I am no longer retrieving all the objects from the store at once. However, upon calling `reloadData` on any of the views, troubles ensue.

Here is the error message from `NSTableView`

```
Cannot update for observer <NSAutounbinderObservance 0x105889dd0> for the key path 
"objectValue.status" from <NSTableCellView 0x105886a80>, most likely because the value
 for the key "objectValue" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent.
 Check the KVO-compliance of the NSTableCellView class.
2012-01-29 11:48:01.304 [62895:707] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92bf6286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff91d3ad5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92bf60ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92bf6044 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff9154b519 -[NSKeyValueNestedProperty object:withObservance:didChangeValueForKeyOrKeys:recurse:forwardingValues:] + 689
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff9154986f NSKeyValueDidChange + 186
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff914f60fb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 130
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff90a2c26d -[NSTableRowData _addViewToRowView:atColumn:row:] + 434
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff90a2bf81 -[NSTableRowData _addViewsToRowView:atRow:] + 200
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff90a2abe3 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:] + 404
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff90a2a9e2 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorRowIndex:inDictionary:withRowAnimation:] + 184
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff90a2a928 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:] + 38
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff90a2a06c -[NSTableRowData _unsafeUpdateVisibleRowEntries] + 448
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff90a29e87 -[NSTableRowData updateVisibleRowViews] + 95
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff909c1c56 -[NSTableView viewWillDraw] + 156
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff909254a2 -[NSScrollView viewWillDraw] + 43
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924f7b -[NSSplitView viewWillDraw] + 67
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924f7b -[NSSplitView viewWillDraw] + 67
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff90924c11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff90923952 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:suppressRecursion:] + 1358
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fff909226c1 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1039
    30  AppKit                              0x00007fff9091e6fa -[NSAnimationManager animationTimerFired:] + 2593
    31  Foundation                          0x00007fff91537014 __NSFireTimer + 102
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92baaf84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92baaad6 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 534
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92b8b471 __CFRunLoopRun + 1617
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92b8aae6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    36  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cdf63d3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
    37  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cdfd58f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 181
    38  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cdfd4ca BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    39  AppKit                              0x00007fff908e63f1 _DPSNextEvent + 659
    40  AppKit                              0x00007fff908e5cf5 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff908e262d -[NSApplication run] + 470
    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff90b6180c NSApplicationMain + 867
```

`IKImageBrowserView` on the other hand would just hang on me without any kind of error message if I were to call its `reloadData`.

So yea, I managed to replace one problem with another, c'est la vie?

Comment: I looked into this issue a bit further and I think the solution could be to implement a proxy for the underlying data. Even though IKImageBrowserView iterate through all the items and ask for them, they don't actually all get called upon immediately, so a proxy as a standing object would seem to do the trick.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540426/telling-ikimagebrowserview-not-to-schedule-preloading/1541379#1541379.
May be it will be helpful.